# PHPmailer sending to user entered mail addresses

Tags: php, phpmailer

As the question says. I have a field on my form called email where the user puts in the managers email address. Is it possible for PHPmailer to use that email address that is entered?

Comment: Yes it is possible :) Do you have any problem?

Comment: i got it :D Thank you i just changed the email address in the code to use the name of the textbox. eg.$email

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, but you need to be careful. Using a user-submitted address as the *from* address is a very bad idea, i.e. **don't** do this:

```
$mail->setFrom($_POST['email']);
```

This is forgery, and will cause your message to fail SPF checks, so it will either not be delivered, or will end up in a spam folder. The right way to do it is this, using a fixed from address, but adding a reply-to address so that replies *do* go to the submitter:

```
$mail->setFrom('me@example.com');
$mail->addReplyTo($_POST['email']);
```

If you want to send *to* a user-submitted address, that's also dangerous - you need to validate heavily if you're not going to become a spam gateway, which really means whitelisting allowed addresses, like this:

```
$allowed = ['bob@example.com', 'carol@example.com', 'alice@example.com'];
if (in_array($_POST['email'], $allowed)) {
    $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);
} else {
    echo 'Bad address';
    exit;
}
```